# Suppose $R$ is a partial order on a set $A$. Prove that every finite, nonempty set $B ⊆ A$ has an $R$-minimal element.

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Proposition:

> Suppose $R$ is a partial order on a set $A$. Prove that
>   every finite, nonempty set $B ⊆ A$ has an $R$-minimal element.

My attempt:

Notation:

If $A$ is a set and $A = \{3,5\}$, then its cardinality will be denoted as

$$|A| = 2 $$

By induction.

**Base case:**

Suppose $B \subseteq A$ and  $|B| = 1$. Then clearly, the only element $B$ has will also be its minimal element.

**Induction step:**

Take some $B' \subseteq A$, such that $|B'| = n$, and $B'$ has a minimal element, say $c$.

Take $z \in A$ such that $z \notin B'$ and let $B = B' \cup \{z\}$.

1. If $cRz$, then minimal element of $B$ will be $c$
2. Suppose $zRc$. Suppose exists $a \in B'$ such that $aRz$. Then by transitivity we have $aRc$. Since $c$ is minimal element, $a = c$. Then it follows that $cRz$ and $z = c$, but this is impossible. Hence provided that $zRc$, $z$ will be the minimal element of $B$.
3. If $\lnot cRz$ and $\lnot zRc$, then $c$ will be the minimal element of $B$.

$\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: You should start with arbitrary $B$ with $|B|=n+1$, and then try to use some subset on $n$-many elements. You your 3, instead of "the minimal element" you should say "a minimal element" (there may be more than one).

Comment: @Mirko Thanks for the review! Could you explain to me, please, why my approach (taking arbitrary $B'$, such that $|B'| = n$ and then letting $B = B' \cup \{z\}$ where $z$ is arbitrary element in $A$) is incorrect?

Comment: If you mean that the $B'$ goes with the so called "induction hypothesis, then instead of saying "take some  $B'$ ", you should say: Suppose that *for every* $B'$ with $|B'|=n$ we have that $B'$ has a minimal element. Now take an *arbitrary* $B$ with $|B|=n+1$. Take any $b\in B$, if $b$ is minimal, we are done. If not, let $B'=B\setminus\{b\}$. Then $ |B'|=n$ and hence by induction hypothesis, $B'$ has a minimal element $c$. The proceed on to argue that $c$ is a minimal element of $B$ too. (If not you will end up with something like $c>b>d$ and get a contradiction.)